# org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: “Widget is disposed” when trying to open AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am running Windows 8 and using Eclipse Kepler Release to create android application.

When I click on the AndroidManifest.xml file in my project, I receive an alert which shows the following error message:

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt".
```

Exception Stack Trace:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:88)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:107)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:328)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:342)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.activate(EclipseContext.java:625)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener$2.run(ShellActivationListener.java:120)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener.activate(ShellActivationListener.java:117)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener.handleEvent(ShellActivationListener.java:73)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_ACTIVATE(Decorations.java:1667)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_ACTIVATE(Shell.java:2151)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4608)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2075)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4977)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.BringWindowToTop(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.bringToTop(Decorations.java:231)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.open(Shell.java:1217)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:798)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.open(InternalDialog.java:327)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.doAddStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:270)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:197)
at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.showStatusAdapter(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:101)
at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:57)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:108)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.java:36)
at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$3.show(JFaceUtil.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.handleException(SafeRunnable.java:67)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:75)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:472)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:344)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.addDisposeListener(Widget.java:214)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.engine.CSSSWTEngineImpl.hookNativeWidget(CSSSWTEngineImpl.java:52)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.getElement(AbstractCSSEngine.java:919)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.dom.ElementAdapter.getElement(ElementAdapter.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.dom.CTabFolderElement.item(CTabFolderElement.java:52)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:481)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:405)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:481)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:405)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:481)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:405)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:481)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:405)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngine.applyStyles(ThemeEngine.java:497)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$10.setClassnameAndId(PartRenderingEngine.java:1267)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.setCSSInfo(SWTPartRenderer.java:92)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.styleStack(WBWRenderer.java:179)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.trackActivePart(WBWRenderer.java:148)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
... 71 more
```

Comment: Closing and opening Eclipse IDE solved the problem. I was copying and pasting .java and .xml files from one project to another. I still don't know what caused it.

Comment: Same issue, same workaround.
Using:
- Android Developer Tools
- Build: v22.6.2-1085508

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Restarting the Eclipse IDE solved the problem.

Comment: Restart worked. I was trying to import 'google-play-services_lib' for gcm purpose as per instructions provided on http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html and faced this error. Observed that after restarting values in 'project.properties' file got changed automatically.

Answer (score 14):

Eclipse - Kepler / Luna / Mars

for me I went to

**...\.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench // folder locaiton.**

and deleted all the content of

**workbench.xmi**

and restarted the application.

Worked for me hopefully will work for you.

Note: Good to take back up before making changes.

Comment: Worked for MyEclipse as well. Thanks Arun

Answer (score 6):

Start Eclipse via command prompt by entering command: `eclipse -clean` solved my problem.

Comment: the file clean cannot be found ,i am getting

Comment: Thanks Camilla! I had already tried -clean on its own but with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

It's much better close the Eclipse and start the Eclipse again rather than restart the Eclipse, it will work faster.

Comment: What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I did little bit change on the file name.

/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi 
above is the original name of workbench.xmi

I rename that on workbenchold.xmi which work for me.

once you rename it must update your eclipse and plugins from the marketplace plus do little bit your 'show view' settings.

Answer (score 0):

Clean a server and restart eclips IDE.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Close Eclipse
2. cd <work-project>
3. mvn clean install
4. Start Eclipse
```