# Eclipse Neon Does Not Start

Tags: eclipse, aptana

Eclipse Neon displays an error message box during startup and will not open. The message gives a file path to a log file. In that file I see this error message:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 4 2 2016-11-13 08:50:49.856
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt".
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com.aptana.editor.css.CSSSourceEditor.isWordWrapEnabled()Z
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.WordWrapToggleAction.isWordWrapEnabled(WordWrapToggleAction.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.WordWrapToggleAction.update(WordWrapToggleAction.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.TextEditorAction.<init>(TextEditorAction.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.WordWrapToggleAction.<init>(WordWrapToggleAction.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.createActions(AbstractTextEditor.java:5898)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.createAction
```

The OS is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I would consider re installation or fresh download from eclipse.org/downloads/.

Answer (score 27):

i found this solution and it worked for me.

I went to directory:

.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench

And renamed

workbench.xmi to workbenchOLD.xmi

I found it here:

[org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: “Widget is disposed” when trying to open AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615286/org-eclipse-swt-swtexception-widget-is-disposed-when-trying-to-open-androidma)

I hope it helped!
See you,

Federico

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you

Comment: Great fix. It would be better to delete workbench.xmi altogether in my opinion.